# Change attributes from ajax inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to change attributes for a newly added element.

This is my code:

```
$("#file-create-form").ajaxSubmit({
     url: formURL,
     success: function(data){
         $('#docdetailtable tbody').find('#file-row-'+data.latest_doc_id).text(newVersion);
         $('#docdetailtable tbody').find('#file-row-'+data.latest_doc_id).attr('id','#file-row-'+data.docID);
         $('#file-row-'+data.latest_doc_id).attr('id','#file-row-'+data.docID);
        //.....
    }
});
```

The first time the code works. But when I fire ajax the second time it won't work.
`$('#file-row-'+data.latest.doc_id)` is a new element because the id was changed. And now ajax won't find it. Is this right?

How can I change an already changed element?

Comment: Store the `latest_doc_id` in some variable and use that instead of the `doc_id` directly. This way the second call will know which element to target.

Comment: latest_doc_id is a return from the AJAX call. Where should i store the variabel? Outside the submit() function? Thanks! :)

Comment: Changing the ID of an element is generally not a good idea. Can you give us a context of your script, explaining to us what exactly you're trying to do?